# Create a variable to equal a dynamically created DOM element

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm working on a function:

```
var container      = $('#container'),
    line1          = $('#line1'),
    line2          = $('#line2'),
    line3          = $('#line3'),
    line4          = $('#line4'),
    postcode       = $('#postcode'),
    addressPicker  = $('#selector'),
    noneOfTheAbove = $('#noneOfTheAbove');

    $(document).on('click', '#noneOfTheAbove', function()
    {
        container.removeClass('hidden');

        noneOfTheAbove.addClass('noDisplayElementImportant');
        addressPicker.addClass('hidden');

        line1.val('');
        line2.val('');
        line3.val('');
        line4.val('');
        postcode.val('');
    });
```

The only problem with this is the DOM gets dynamically created on a button click. So using the variables like this doesn't work becuase on $(document).ready() they don't exist. How can I assign dynamic DOM elements to a variable? Would it be something like `$(document).find('#idHere')`?

Thanks

## UPDATE 1

making vars global then local (using charlietfl answer):

```
var container,
    line1,
    line2,
    line3,
    line4,
    postcode,
    addressPicker,
    noneOfTheAbove;

 $(document).on('click', '#noneOfTheAbove', function()
 {
     container      = $('#container');
     line1          = $('#line1');
     line2          = $('#line2');
     line3          = $('#line3');
     line4          = $('#line4');
     postcode       = $('#postcode');
     addressPicker  = $('#selector');
     noneOfTheAbove = $('#noneOfTheAbove');

     container.removeClass('hidden');

     noneOfTheAbove.addClass('noDisplayElementImportant');
     addressPicker.addClass('hidden');

     line1.val('');
     line2.val('');
     line3.val('');
     line4.val('');
     postcode.val('');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define those variables inside the event handler when they do exist

```
$(document).on('click', '#noneOfTheAbove', function() {

  var container = $('#container'),
    line1 = $('#line1'),
    line2 = $('#line2'),
    line3 = $('#line3'),
    line4 = $('#line4'),
    postcode = $('#postcode'),
    addressPicker = $('#selector'),
    noneOfTheAbove = $('#noneOfTheAbove');
  container.removeClass('hidden');

  noneOfTheAbove.addClass('noDisplayElementImportant');
  addressPicker.addClass('hidden');

  line1.val('');
  line2.val('');
  line3.val('');
  line4.val('');
  postcode.val('');
});
```

Comment: Since you made them local to the function, they are not useful outside of that function, hence you do not need them at all.

Comment: @ANS *"don't need them at all"* is subjective...depending on how many times any of them might be queried in dom. I agree based on basic code shown but also don't know if actual code is more complex. As for declaring them outside there is no reason for that shown in question either

Answer (score 1):

Do not eager load them as they are dynamic. Go with lazy loading which means that use them when you require them.

```
    var container,
    line1,line,.. ;
    $(document).on('click', '#noneOfTheAbove', function()
        {  
            container = $('#container');
            container.removeClass('hidden');

            ... // others

            ...
        });
```